# Assembly, Loop with unsigned char vector

Tags: loops, pointers, assembly

I don't understand what happens in this Loop written in assembly language with 32-bit registers. This is the code:

```
void main() {

    unsigned char Vet[100];
    unsigned short int Mat = 8805;
    unsigned short Ris;

    __asm {
        MOV AX, Mat
        MOV BYTE PTR Vet[10], AL
        MOV BYTE PTR Vet[13], 99
        MOV BYTE PTR Vet[16], AH
        LEA ESI, Vet
        ADD ESI, 9
        XOR EBX, EBX
        MOV ECX, 3
        L1: XOR BL, [ESI + 1]
            ADD ESI, 3
            LOOP L1
            MOV Ris, BX
    }
    printf("\nRis: %d\n\n", Ris);
}
```

`L1` set `BL=65h` the first time because `BL` starts by 0. Ok.
The second time i suppose to have `65h XOR 99h`, because `ESI=Vect[9+3+1]`.
So i expect `FCh` as result in `BL`, but compiler returns `06h`!
I made test with a simple `XOR` between `65h` and `99h`, and is like i thought: FCh. The problem maybe in the `Vet` index, but where?

Comment: Have you single stepped through the code instruction by instruction to see how things change? If you were to use the debugger you'd probably realize that you have a slight typo (or I assume a typo).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

it's `99`, not `99h`. `65h xor 99 = 6`.

Comment: What a genius! Thank you.

Comment: @caramelleamare: your brain will insist on reading what you wanted to write/read, instead of reading the true content. You have to learn to force your brain to read it character by character in these weird cases. While debugging, try it again, if there is some automatically shown memory value somewhere (so you would have chance to see `63h` instead of expected `99h`). If not, you can surely display in watch window `Vet[esi + 1]`? That would be probably another huge hint. These nasty typos often take even 3-5 tries, until the brain finally reveals the truth.

Comment: I looked around to see something, but i couldn't see the `63h`. Maybe i don't know exactly where to look. What i could do was give a look to ascii table and find that `char c` setted in `Vet` in the Locals window(Visual Studio 2015) is `99 decimal .> 63h`. I tought problem was something like that, but i couldn't find it. However today in the exam i find excatly `99` in a `mov` operand! I would never have done it rigth(like i hope i've done) without this question. Is there a way on VS to look inside in a deeper way than `F10` or `F11` to check situations like this?

Comment: @caramelleamare: F11 in the disassembly window is the final instance, going per single machine code instruction. You complete it by checking the registers window to see the actual state of CPU, and watch/locals to check memory content. IIRC you can use some modifiers in watch to adjust value formatting, I think "variable,h" was hexa formatting? I haven't used VS for 10+ years, so I'm not sure how the debugger did change. Some googled links: [Format Specifiers](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/75w45ekt.aspx)| [... Registers Window](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/62680774.aspx)

Comment: Yes, i follow registers step by step to see what happens and if it's what i expect. That instruction doesn't load `99h` in some register, just set the value into Vet and update `eip` reg. As i said, it has been my double distraction: i did not check which is hexadecimal(yes, `h` is for hex) value for that char `c`, and, the first of all, i did not see that was `99` and not `99h` reading the code.